# hide Process In Cmd xcopy Batch

Tags: batch-file, echo, hide

Im Creating a Batch file

```
@Echo Off
xcopy /y /s /i /e C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\users c:\
```

i want to hide the copy proccess

Comment: Redirect any output to the `NUL` device, `XCopy "C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\users" "c:\" /Y /S /I /E >Nul`.

Comment: Redirects STDOUT to NUL.  Not any output.
To redirect STDERR, FD 2 would also need to be piped to NUL or STDOUT first.

Also, aren't /S and /E mutually exclusive?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I said to redirect any output to the `NUL` device, which is absolutely the correct answer. My example shows only the STDOUT being redirected, but that's irrelevant to the preceding statement. Also, the options chosen by the OP were irrelevant to the answer, especially as using both does not affect the resulting action.

Comment: @Compo, you TOTALLY provided a solution to "I want to hide the copy process".. I wasn't trying to be smarmy.  It was the ambiguity of the word "any" that I clued in on and thought that I would point out that STDERR wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. EDIT: @Compo you are right... try

```
xcopy  C:\ProgramData\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\users c:\ /y /s /i /e >NUL
```

Comment: this is what i got "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Works, Thanks For the help